# How to use Dynamic loaded content with jquery bbq

Tags: jquery, back-button, hashchange, jquery-bbq

First of all, i am new to jQuery. I found that my web application face a problem in which a user is unable to navigate back to the previous page or even refresh the page. It's making it re-direct to the first page of the web app.
Here's part of my script

```
$(function() {
$("#register").click(function(evt) {
    $("#pages").load("register.php")
    evt.preventDefault();
})
})
```

Basically, when user click on the `<li>`, the page will load another content from another page.

```
<li><a id="register" href="">register</a></li>
```

I know that jQuery BBQ could solve it, but I don't know how to use it. Can anyone give me some hint?

Comment: I think the div "#pages" is the one that contains all the page right? You won't be able to go previous page because you are in the same page that your new page is loading and everything is in DOM. Also, when refreshing page, your browser thinks is the same page so the content in the div "#pages" comes as first time. Why you want BBQ? Am I correct?

Comment: ya..u r rite...everything was in the pages...as i nid a bbq..because i nid to allow my user to use the back button. and also if i go to my form..in that case..a server script validation fail...it will return to my first page..and not my form...
any idea to do tat? i don mind to change my code as now still beginning of developing///

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to your comment, I think you want to use BBQ to change pages and avoid the problem of refreshing and going back to pages with jQuery load.

I made you an example.

**Download link:**

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15208254/stackoverflow/jquery-bbq-example.zip

Please, run it in your localhost, because it has 2 PHP files.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: hi, thx for the content, i will test it now and return you the result :)

Comment: @dejiar sure, just let me know

Comment: isit necessary to use `<head><body>` tag on every page? since if i no use it, the code cnt navigate correctly

Comment: Its better to use it because if someone wants to navigate your url directly from the browser, what title will appear for the page? Also, when using html, you need to follow the correct syntax or html structure.

Comment: ok...thx for the information...I think my problem solved after 2 days of research.. THX!

Comment: @dejiar Nice to help you. Please, don't forget to click on the "check" next to my answer if you think is the correct one. I am telling you this because you are new here :-)